# Removing "Z" part from XMLGregorianCalender

Tags: java, xsd, gregorian-calendar

When I do like below,

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.setTime(startTime);  // startTime Date
DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
```

I get Output like `2015-04-15T11:04:30.000Z`.

I want it to be like `2015-04-15T11:04:30.000`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follow

```
DatatypeFactory df; 
try { 
    df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance(); 
    return df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")); 
} catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) { 
    // throw new SomeRuntimeException(e); 
}
```

Or Extend new class from `XMLGregorianCalendar`, override `toXMLFormat` and then delegate ALL the other methods to the contained instance.

```
class CustomXMLGregorianCalendar extends XMLGregorianCalendar
{
    XMLGregorianCalendar calendar;

    CustomXMLGregorianCalendar(XMLGregorianCalendar calendar){
        this.calendar = calendar;
    }

    public String toXMLFormat() {
        String text = calendar.toXMLFormat();
        int pos = text.indexOf('Z');

        return pos < 0 ? text : text.substring(0,pos);
    }

    public void setTimezone(int offset){ calendar.setTimezone( offset ); }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Outdated answer. Check Ignas Vaitekunas answer belong to actual answer (Worked for me).

Answer (score 16):

Accepted answer or my Java seems to be outdated because I received this error:
`The method newXMLGregorianCalendar(String) in the type DatatypeFactory is not applicable for the arguments (SimpleDateFormat)`

and I didn't want to extend, so I solved it by removing timezone:

```
    xmlCalendar.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```

Comment: DatatypeConstants is by default present java or this constant class added manually. If yes then what is value of FIELD_UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove only "Z" from XMLGregorianCalendar object just call this method.

xmlDate.setTimezone( DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED )

Comment: DatatypeConstants is by default present java or this constant class added manually. If yes then what is value of FIELD_UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your Locale Timezone, to achieve what you need transform the date using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

**UPDATE** when you comment:

> *I tried formatting it to a String then again parsing it to a Date. Then setting time in Calender object. Does not work. Still i get output as "2015-04-15T11:04:30.000Z"*

You must understand that `Calendar` or `Date` objects are stored in it's own format, another thing is how you print them, so in this case, to see `2015-04-15T11:04:30.000Z` in the `Calendar` representation does not matters, what you need is to have the correct date `2015-04-15` at `11:04:30` show this in the desired format is just to make user-friendly your output.

The output you get is from [Calendar.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toString()) and the method doc says:

> Return a string representation of this calendar. **This method is intended to be used only for debugging purposes, and the format of the returned string may vary between implementations**. The returned string may be empty but may not be null.

**So in order to store the date and the time, your `Calendar` object is correct. In order to print it, you have to transform it into a `String`.**

Comment: I tried formatting it to a String then again parsing it to a Date. Then setting time in Calender object. Does not work. Still i get output as "2015-04-15T11:04:30.000Z".

Comment: Calendar's ´toString()` method has is own implementation!!! you need to override this if you want to change it's output, or simply print a string formatted, you dont need to care about how it is stored....

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I'm putting this here for anyone that comes along after, but solved my issue similar to how Ignas Vaitekunas eventually did it.

I used

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());
xgc.setYear(year);
xgc.setMonth(month);
xgc.setDay(day);
xgc.setHour(hour);
xgc.setMinute(min);
xgc.setSecond(second);
xgc.setTimezone(timezone);
```

Where year, month, day, hour, min, second, timezone are all initially set to `DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED`.

I pull values from a formatted text field that's displayed to the user as '    -  -  T  :  :  Z'. The user fills in what information they have, I split and parse the string and if I have a value for the timezone (or second, or minute, or hour etc) I set it, if not it gets fed to xgc as and undefined field. Then the XML Gregorian Calendar will print out only what values aren't undefined.

Answer (score -1):

I had that situation and it was solved, using this line:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar dateNew = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2017-09-06T21:08:14");
```